# how to get the uppercase value items in the combo box ext js?

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs, ext.net

How to populate the combo box with uppercase value items for the below: Thank you

I have below **code 1** and store in the view calling web api as in store reader in **code 2**:

### Code 1 :

```
comboBox.store.load({
    callback: function () {
        comboBox.setValue(params.val)
    }
});
```

### Code 2 :

```
Ext.define('App.View.Value', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.App-View-Value',
    labelAlign: 'right',
    emptyText: 'Value',
    valueField: 'Id',
    displayField: 'Name',
    forceSelection: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    editable: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    lastQuery:'',
    store: {
        type: 'webapi',
        autoLoad: false,
        api: {
            read: 'api/filter/getVal'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by iterating over records in store's callback function.

**Code snippet:**

```
comboBox.store.load({
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        records.forEach(function (rec, index) {
            rec.set('Name', rec.get('Name').toUpperCase());
        })
    }
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jes)

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: what do I do if I need to change the Id to uppercase instead of just the display. Because I am populating the combo box during cell click in the grid and due to case sensitive, the above combo box is not loading with the data from the grid. Thank you.

Comment: you can use `id` in `rec.set` method instead of `Name`

Answer (score 0):

If `params.val` is a String you can do a UpperCase transformation with `.toUpperCase()` like this

```
comboBox.store.load({
    callback: function () {
        comboBox.setValue(params.val.toUpperCase())
    }
});
```

Comment: That will set the value that we wanted to set in the combobox to uppercase but what about the items that loads in the combo box itself.